# give type to anonymous type in linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

What I'm trying to do is to get particular values from my DB and parse that into view to display it in the table.
I had same problem as in [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .... {Models.App} but what I passed is {Models.App, System.Double}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521775/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-models-app-but-what) and tried to solve my problem in the similar way. So basically I created a class in the model that has:

```
 public Vehicle manur_name {get; set;}
 public Vehicle manur_date { get; set; }
 public Vehicle daily_hire_rate { get; set; }
```

but then when I use it in my controller in the linq query it gives me and error.

```
 var s = from veh in db.Vehicles
 join c in db.VehicleCategories on veh.vehicle_category_code equals  c.
 join m in db.Models on veh.model_code equals m.model_code
 join man in db.Manufacturers on veh.manufacturer_code equals man.manufacturer_code
 where c.vehicle_category_description == cat && m.body_style == b                         
            select new CarClass {
                          manur_name = man.manufacturer_name, 
                          manur_date = m.model_code, 
                          daily_hire_rate = veh.daily_hire_rate};
```

It gives me the error:

> error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to
>   'carRentalMVC.Models.Vehicle'  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string'
>   to 'carRentalMVC.Models.Vehicle'   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'string' to 'carRentalMVC.Models.Vehicle'

Here is what I have in controller after fixing the problem:

```
        CarRentalDatabaseDataContext db = new CarRentalDatabaseDataContext();
    public ActionResult Index(String cat, String b, String sort)
    {
        String day_hire = "Daily hire rate";
        String man_date = "Manufacturing date";
        string man_n = "Manufacturer's name";

        var s = db.Vehicles.Where(c => c.Model.body_style == b)
             .Select(u => new CarClassViewModel { 
                 manur_name = u.Manufacturer.manufacturer_name, 
                 model_code = u.model_code,
                 daily_hire_rate = u.daily_hire_rate,
                 manur_date = u.manufacturing_date
             })
             .Distinct(); //I don't need repeating data

        //this is for sorting them, but I haven't implemented this in the view yet. 
        if (sort == man_n){s = s.OrderBy(c=>c.manur_name);}
        else if (sort == man_date){s = s.OrderBy(c =>c.manur_date);}
        else if (sort == day_hire){s = s.OrderBy(c => c.daily_hire_rate);}
        else{s = s.OrderBy(c => c.daily_hire_rate);}

        var v = s.Select(u => new CarClassViewModel
        {
            manur_name = u.manur_date,
            model_code = u.model_code,
            daily_hire_rate = u.daily_hire_rate,
        }); //this is for returning values I need

        return View(v); //I've tried View(v.ToList()) as well
    }
```

Now this returns empty rows in my table. Does it matter that I'm not parsing in data for the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Your data model is very messed up. Even leaving the naming conventions aside, look at your properties:

```
public Vehicle manur_name {get; set;}
public Vehicle manur_date { get; set; }
public Vehicle daily_hire_rate { get; set; }
```

The manufacturer name of a car *isn't* a vehicle - it's likely to be a string. The manufacturing date of a car *isn't* a vehicle - it's likely to be a `DateTime`. The daily hire rate of a car *isn't* a vehicle - it's likely to be a `decimal`. So your model should look like this:

```
public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
public DateTime ManufacturingDate { get; set; }
public decimal DailyHireRate { get; set; }
```

Get your data model right, and everything else should become a *lot* simpler. Having said that, this looks pretty suspicious too:

```
manur_date = m.model_code
```

A "date" and a "code" don't sound like the same thing to me.

Comment: thanks)) I figured out that types assign to the variables weren't correct. Now everything in my code compiles but it doesn't really return anything... what should I parse in to the view?

Comment: @NurkaKindova: It's hard to know what you're doing wrong - please give more details in a new question. (You've got a lot of joins there, and filtering - any part of that could be filtering out data you don't want it to.)

Comment: Ok, I modified the question and added the code that I currently have. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @NurkaKindova: No, you should ask a *new question*. You've got a different problem, so that should be a different question.